# System can't boot with full SSD in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: boot, 18.04, ssd

I met the following issue a few weeks back. I noticed that my SSD was full so I wanted to delete some of my useless data to free up space. For some reason after deleting the files I could not empty the trash.

I thought it must be some kind of bug so I rebooted my computer. After reboot the booting process stopped at loading the Ubuntu logo. I had to reinstall the whole system. Does anyone know what could cause it and how can I prevent such things?

Answer (score 2):

You should have stopped after booting the live session. You could have deleted files from there by mounting your disks.

General sollution: do not use your root for personal files and keep either /home on a partition or put the directories in /home on a separate partition.